# Alternating Slides with Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a beamer slide set that contains a list that gets revealed over multiple steps, something like this:

```
\begin{frame}{Result Overview}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Result 1
        \item<2-> Result 2
        \item<3-> ...
        \item<4-> ...
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

And a set of frames presenting the results like this:

```
\begin{frame}{Result 1}
  ...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Result 2}
  ...
\end{frame}
```

Is there a way to have those slides displayed in an alternating fashion like this

- Result Overview (page 1)
- Result 1
- Result Overview (page 2)
- Result 2
- ...

Without copy pasting the "Result Overview" frame before each Result frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\againframe` macro is your new best friend:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}<1>[label=overview]
\frametitle{Result Overview}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Result 1
        \item<2-> Result 2
        \item<3-> ...
        \item<4-> ...
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Result 1}
  ...
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{overview}

\begin{frame}{Result 2}
  ...
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I also noticed I can add ranges like `<2-3>` for a frame, and also for the `againframe` macro. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @Tiim You're welcome!